# Why too many releases lead to crash in ARC?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm watching a WWDC 2013 video called "Fixing memory Issues"

When the presenter introduces retains, releases and retain cycles. He briefly mentioned that too many releases leads to crashes. I didn't get it. What does too many releases means in this case?

In my understanding, 1 reference count means +1 in ARC for that object, with many things things reference to each other, it may exist some reference that are not used by other codes. Thus leads to leaks. But why too many releases lead to crashes? Is 0 the minimal counting number that an object can go? If so, why will it lead to crashes?

[image]

Comment: A long time ago, when dinosaurs ruled the earth, Objective-C required that you manually managed what ARC does automatically. The point of the bullet in question is that if you released something manually that was needed for execution, the app would throw an exception. As an aside, your time is probably better spent learning Swift.

Comment: @Adrian Thank you for the background information and suggestions! I'm indeed trying to learn Swift. When I watched the WWDC 2018 video about pages in memory, this 2013 video is linked below. I found it explains reside, dirty, swap memory pretty well. But I would never have known that manual reference counting will throw error if released too early. Guess I'm a bit too spoiled by ARC and lost sense of what manual really means.Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slide you have shown refers to the manual processes you had to use before Automatic Reference Counting (ARC).

Without ARC the programmer is responsible for calling `retain` and `release` to manage the reference count on an object.

The reference count is positive, non-zero while the object is still required and 0 when it was no longer required.

If you called `release` when the reference count was already 0 then your program was terminated as it indicates you have an error in your code.

Because tracking when an object is no longer required across complex execution flows is difficult, under and over releasing (resulting in leaks and crashes) is common if you don't use ARC

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation of the whole process. I learnt a lot from it! Now I appreciate ARC even more.